# Can I modify the byte code of a Java method in the runtime?

Tags: java, proxy, hook, bytecode, javassist

I am writing a plugin of another large java program .

I want to modify some byte code of some java method of the java program during runtime, so that I can intercept the method calls (namely, inject some hooking code into the method).

Any way can achieve this?

PS:

I've checked the following approaches:

1.change the classloader of the java program. (we CANNOT change it)
2.use java proxy. (We CANNOT use java proxy, because java proxy would create a new proxy object. We DON'T use the proxy object. We need to hook the java program's object, and Use that object)
3. use -javaagent option ( we CANNOT add the commandline option for the java program.)

PS more **[Edited again]**:
My classes was loaded by ext class loader (I put my jar files in JAVA_HOME\lib\ext folder).
The large java program is an applet program loaded by Browser. When the browser start the applet, it also loads my classes.

PS more more **[Edited again]**:
Although it's running in Applet. I can have full permission. Because I can modify java.policy and java.security file.

Thanks,
Calvin

Comment: If you're running into security restrictions, they probably don't want you to be doing this anyway.

Comment: Hi Antimony, I have full permission. I can modify policy files in JAVA_HOME\lib\security

Comment: so why not just modify the classes offline?

Answer (score 6):

Just use -javaagent opiton,  which is used to modify the bytecode at runtime. You can find more about -javaagent from [This Link](http://www.javabeat.net/2012/06/introduction-to-java-agents/) or from [This Link](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/07/javaagent-option.html)

Comment: Hi Anish, I am writing applet. So -javaagent option is banned in 1.7u25 and above for security reason. Any other approaches?

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries which you can use. See for example [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries).
Once a class was already loaded/initialized by the VM it will be impossible to manipulate, though.

By the way, in principle you can also just replace the class to be 'hooked' with your own proxy class file. As long as the class' visible interface does not change this may work. (Sub-classes of the class may horribly fail at runtime though.) This replacement can be as easy as changing the classpath so that your class of the same name will be found first, before the original one. Delegating to the original class of the same name may be a little more complex in this case.

Comment: Hi Hanno, I want to modify the bytecode after loaded by the class loader. Which library I should use?

Comment: I'd recommend a look into [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist) to see if it does the trick for you. It "enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to modify a class file when the JVM loads it."

Comment: Hi Hanno, It's "before", however what I need is "after" : "enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to modify a class file **before** the JVM loads it"

Comment: Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but the process would be a bit tricky, as you would operate directly with memory. For this purpose, you'd look at unofficial documentation on sun.misc package and its Unsafe class.

- Warning 1: the Unsafe class would be removed in JDK 9 according to official sources.
- Warning 2: the Sun company would not take responsibility for your code to work correctly, as this class should not be used at all, and exists for system usage only.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not possible. First off, bytecode is immutable after classloading. The JVM provides several APIs that can be used to do something like this, but they are obviously highly privileged.

If you're running in a low privilege environment like a browser Applet, then you're obviously not going to be allowed to do this, and any method you could should be considered a security vulnerability.

But the question is why you are using applets in the first place, and why you want to modify code after loading. There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Antimony, I can modify the java.policy file, so I can have all permissions. You mentioned "JVM provides several APIs...". Could you please indicate what are these APIs?

Comment: Well Java agents are the main one, but you already rejected that.

Comment: "First off, bytecode is immutable after classloading. " it's not, agent can't be loaded in runtime without any arguments to JVM, but this require few tricks and JDK JVM, or even more tricks on normal JVM.

Comment: @GotoFinal - You can add dynamic agents as well.