# Java ASM Bytecode - Find all instructions belonging to a specific method-call

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

**Hi.**

I want to find the range of instructions between the **start** and the **end** of a method-call.
I do not want to simply just change the method-call owner/name/desc.

With the expected result, I want to be able to do:

1. Completely remove a method call
2. Modify the method call by adding new arguments either in-front or after

I've been trying different techniques to achieve this:

1. ASM Analyzer (using SourceInterpreter)
2. Looping the instruction set, forward and reversed, to try and locate the `start` and `end`, by either counting instruction count or counting stack heights
3. Searching through StackOverflow (found nothing that resulted in the expected behavior)

I'll give you some examples of what exactly I want, in-case there's any confusion here.
First of all, look at my testing code below, then come back up here.

I wish to find/remove the whole method-call to `anotherMethod4` and replace it with a simple `true`, resulting in this code:

```
    System.out.println(
        anotherMethod1(
            anotherMethod2("a", "b") ?
                "c" : anotherMethod3("d", "e") ? "f" : "g",
                true ? "j" : "k"
        ) ? "l" : "m"
    );
```

I wish to find/remove the whole method-call to `anotherMethod1` and replace it with a simple `false`, resulting in this code:

```
    System.out.println(
        false ? "l" : "m"
    );
```

I wish to remove the whole method-call to `System.out.println`, resulting in this code:

```
    private Main()
    {

    }
```

This must surely be possible?

This is my current testing code:

```
private Main()
{
    System.out.println(
        anotherMethod1(
            anotherMethod2("a", "b") ?
                "c" : anotherMethod3("d", "e") ? "f" : "g",
                anotherMethod4("h", "i") ? "j" : "k"
        ) ? "l" : "m"
    );
}

boolean anotherMethod1(String str, String oof)
{
    return true;
}
boolean anotherMethod2(String str, String oof)
{
    return true;
}
boolean anotherMethod3(String str, String oof)
{
    return true;
}
boolean anotherMethod4(String str, String oof)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: See these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308351/is-there-a-java-classfile-bytecode-editor-to-edit-instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268011/can-i-modify-the-byte-code-of-a-java-method-in-the-runtime

Comment: @armagedescu First link: Yes I know this, but I want to do it programmatically, not myself through a GUI. I am using the ASM library. Second link: That question asks for runtime modification, not what I want.

Comment: Any byte code has specifications: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/. Such specifications are used by developers of languages running on that codes, like jython, groove, jruby and many others. So, generally speaking you can do this. Write your own byte code parser and rewrite any part.

Comment: I know you're trying to help, I appreciate it, but I already know all of this. I am fully able to parse bytecode, modify bytecode, and write bytecode back into .class files and run them. I just struggle with everything I wrote in my question. ASM gives me all the control I need to do what I want, I just don't know how to correctly use ASM to achieve my expected result..

Comment: I have written such a patcher for native windows code: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions . You can use native at the points where java makes native calls, without modifying the byte code. Java calls C runtime at some point, and you can intercept that points.

Comment: Cool! But still not what I need! :P I don't want to intercept, I want to modify the binary file so it can be used anywhere without the need to also intercept anything at runtime. I might be explaining this bad.

Comment: I don't know the byte code. But in native code there is such practice of overwriting the code with NOPs which is simple byte 0x90. Java byte code might have such NOPs as well.

Comment: See the NOP is right here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.nop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210734/discussion-between-hovercatz-and-armagedescu).

Comment: Since a method call consists of exactly one instruction, the term “the start and the end of a method-call” is very confusing. If I get it correctly, you want to identify all instructions whose purpose is to push the argument values for the specific invocation. Am I right? This is not a trivial task as the code may have side effects, e.g. `method(variable = value)`, which can’t be removed, e.g. when would lead to an uninitialized variable. For bytecode not stemming from regular source code, things may be even worse.

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right! If we can ignore the fact that "removing instructions might leave uninitialized variables", how could this be done?

Comment: May I ask *why* you need to do that?

Comment: I just wish to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The arguments to a method invocation can have side effects, e.g `method(variable = value)`, which might even be impossible to remove, e.g. when would lead to accessing an uninitialized variable after the removed invocation. On the bytecode level, the instructions belonging to the argument evaluation can be interleaved with arbitrary unrelated instructions.

But when we limit the scope, we can have a solution. In your example, all invocations are `invokevirtual` instructions invoked on either, the implied `this` or the value of a `static` field. For these invocations, we can indeed use ASM’s `Analyzer` with `SourceInterpreter` to identify the initial `aload` or `getstatic` instruction and assume all instruction from this one and the invocation instruction as belonging to the method call expression.

We can use code like

```
public class IdentifyCall {
    static IdentifyCall getInputs(
        String internalClassName, MethodNode toAnalyze) throws AnalyzerException {

        Map<AbstractInsnNode, Set<AbstractInsnNode>> sources = new HashMap<>();
        SourceInterpreter i = new SourceInterpreter();
        Analyzer<SourceValue> analyzer = new Analyzer<>(i);
        return new IdentifyCall(toAnalyze.instructions, analyzer.analyze(internalClassName, toAnalyze));
    }
    private final InsnList instructions;
    private final Frame<SourceValue>[] frames;

    private IdentifyCall(InsnList il, Frame<SourceValue>[] analyzed) {
        instructions = il;
        frames = analyzed;
    }
    int[] getSpan(AbstractInsnNode i) {
        MethodInsnNode mn = (MethodInsnNode)i;
        // can't use getArgumentsAndReturnSizes, as for the frame, double and long do not count as 2
        int nArg = mn.desc.startsWith("()")? 0: Type.getArgumentTypes(mn.desc).length;
        int end = instructions.indexOf(mn);
        Frame<SourceValue> f = frames[end];
        SourceValue receiver = f.getStack(f.getStackSize() - nArg - 1);
        if(receiver.insns.size() != 1) throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        AbstractInsnNode n = receiver.insns.iterator().next();
        if(n.getOpcode() != Opcodes.ALOAD && n.getOpcode() != Opcodes.GETSTATIC)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(""+n.getOpcode());
        return new int[] { instructions.indexOf(n), end };
    }
}
```

and demonstrate it with the following example

```
public class IdentifyCallExample {
    private void toAnalyze() {
        System.out.println(
            anotherMethod1(
                anotherMethod2("a", "b") ?
                    "c" : anotherMethod3("d", "e") ? "f" : "g",
                    anotherMethod4("h", "i") ? "j" : "k"
            ) ? "l" : "m"
        );
    }

    boolean anotherMethod1(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean anotherMethod2(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean anotherMethod3(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean anotherMethod4(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalyzerException, IOException {
        Class<?> me = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass();
        ClassReader r = new ClassReader(me.getResourceAsStream(me.getSimpleName()+".class"));
        ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
        r.accept(cn, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG|ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
        MethodNode toAnalyze = null;
        for(MethodNode mn: cn.methods)
            if(mn.name.equals("toAnalyze")) {
                toAnalyze = mn;
                break;
            }

        List<int[]> invocations = new ArrayList<>();
        final InsnList instructions = toAnalyze.instructions;

        IdentifyCall identifyCall
            = IdentifyCall.getInputs(me.getName().replace('.', '/'), toAnalyze);

        for(int ix = 0, num = instructions.size(); ix < num; ix++) {
            AbstractInsnNode instr = instructions.get(ix);
            if(instr.getOpcode()!= Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL) continue;
            invocations.add(identifyCall.getSpan(instr));
        }

        printIt(invocations, instructions);
    }

    private static void printIt(List<int[]> invocations, final InsnList instructions) {
        List<Level> levels = toTree(invocations);
        Textifier toText = new Textifier();
        TraceMethodVisitor tmv = new TraceMethodVisitor(toText);
        for(int ix = 0, num = instructions.size(); ix < num; ix++) {
            AbstractInsnNode instr = instructions.get(ix);
            boolean line = false;
            level: for(Level l: levels) {
                if(ix >= l.lo && ix <= l.hi) {
                    for(int[] b: l.branches) {
                        if(ix < b[0] || ix > b[1]) continue;
                        System.out.print(line?
                                (b[0] == ix? b[1] == ix? "─[": "┬─": b[1] == ix? "┴─": "┼─"):
                                (b[0] == ix? b[1] == ix? " [": "┌─": b[1] == ix? "└─": "│ "));
                        line |= b[0] == ix || b[1] == ix;
                        continue level;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(line? "──": "  ");
            }
            instr.accept(tmv);
            System.out.print(toText.text.get(0));
            toText.text.clear();
        }
    }
    static class Level {
        int lo, hi;
        ArrayDeque<int[]> branches=new ArrayDeque<>();

        Level(int[] b) { lo=b[0]; hi=b[1]; branches.add(b); }
        boolean insert(int[] b) {
            if(b[1]<=lo) { branches.addFirst(b); lo=b[0]; }
            else if(b[0]>=hi) { branches.addLast(b); hi=b[1]; }
            else return b[0]>lo && b[1] < hi
              && (b[0]+b[1])>>1 > (lo+hi)>>1? tryTail(b, lo, hi): tryHead(b, lo, hi);
            return true;
        }
        private boolean tryHead(int[] b, int lo, int hi) {
            int[] head=branches.removeFirst();
            try {
                if(head[1] > b[0]) return false;
                if(branches.isEmpty() || (lo=branches.getFirst()[0])>=b[1]) {
                  branches.addFirst(b);
                  return true;
                }
                else return b[0]>lo && b[1] < hi
                  && (b[0]+b[1])>>1 > (lo+hi)>>1? tryTail(b, lo, hi): tryHead(b, lo, hi);
            } finally { branches.addFirst(head); }
        }
        private boolean tryTail(int[] b, int lo, int hi) {
            int[] tail=branches.removeLast();
            try {
                if(tail[0] < b[1]) return false;
                if(branches.isEmpty() || (hi=branches.getLast()[1])<=b[0]) {
                  branches.addLast(b);
                  return true;
                }
                else return b[0]>lo && b[1] < hi
                  && (b[0]+b[1])>>1 > (lo+hi)>>1? tryTail(b, lo, hi): tryHead(b, lo, hi);
            } finally { branches.addLast(tail); }
        }
    }
    static List<Level> toTree(List<int[]> list) {
        if(list.isEmpty()) return Collections.emptyList();
        if(list.size()==1) return Collections.singletonList(new Level(list.get(0)));
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(b -> b[1] - b[0]));
        ArrayList<Level> l=new ArrayList<>();
        insert: for(int[] b: list) {
            for(Level level: l) if(level.insert(b)) continue insert;
            l.add(new Level(b));
        }
        if(l.size() > 1) Collections.reverse(l);
        return l;
    }
}
```

which will print

```
┌─────    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
│ ┌───    ALOAD 0
│ │ ┌─    ALOAD 0
│ │ │     LDC "a"
│ │ │     LDC "b"
│ │ └─    INVOKEVIRTUAL simple/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod2 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│ │       IFEQ L0
│ │       LDC "c"
│ │       GOTO L1
│ │      L0
│ │ ┌─    ALOAD 0
│ │ │     LDC "d"
│ │ │     LDC "e"
│ │ └─    INVOKEVIRTUAL simple/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod3 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│ │       IFEQ L2
│ │       LDC "f"
│ │       GOTO L1
│ │      L2
│ │       LDC "g"
│ │      L1
│ │ ┌─    ALOAD 0
│ │ │     LDC "h"
│ │ │     LDC "i"
│ │ └─    INVOKEVIRTUAL simple/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod4 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│ │       IFEQ L3
│ │       LDC "j"
│ │       GOTO L4
│ │      L3
│ │       LDC "k"
│ │      L4
│ └───    INVOKEVIRTUAL simple/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod1 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│         IFEQ L5
│         LDC "l"
│         GOTO L6
│        L5
│         LDC "m"
│        L6
└─────    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
          RETURN
```

When we want to support more complex receiver expressions or `static` methods, whose first argument can be an arbitrary expression, things get more complicated. The `Frame<SourceValue>` allows us to identify the instructions which pushed the current values to the operand stack, but in case of an expression like `a + b`, it would be the `iadd` instruction only and we have to analyze the `iadd` instruction’s frame to get its inputs. Instead of implementing this for every kind of instruction, it’s easier to extend the interpreter, to get the information and store it, e.g in a `Map`, as `Analyzer` has done this work already. Then, we can collect all inputs recursively.

But this only provides the direct and indirect input sources, but in case of conditional expressions, we also need the input(s) to the condition. For this, we have to identify and store the conditional branches. Whenever an input is reported to potentially originate from different source instructions, we have to check the related branches and add their conditions.

Then we use again the simplifying assumption, that all instructions between the first and last also belong to the invocation expression.

The more elaborated code looks like

```
public class IdentifyCall {
    private final InsnList instructions;
    private final Map<AbstractInsnNode, Set<SourceValue>> sources;
    private final TreeMap<int[],AbstractInsnNode> conditionals;

    private IdentifyCall(InsnList il,
            Map<AbstractInsnNode, Set<SourceValue>> s, TreeMap<int[], AbstractInsnNode> c) {
        instructions = il;
        sources = s;
        conditionals = c;
    }

    Set<AbstractInsnNode> getAllInputsOf(AbstractInsnNode instr) {
        Set<AbstractInsnNode> source = new HashSet<>();
        List<SourceValue> pending = new ArrayList<>(sources.get(instr));
        for (int pIx = 0; pIx < pending.size(); pIx++) {
            SourceValue sv = pending.get(pIx);
            final boolean branch = sv.insns.size() > 1;
            for(AbstractInsnNode in: sv.insns) {
                if(source.add(in))
                    pending.addAll(sources.getOrDefault(in, Collections.emptySet()));
                if(branch) {
                    int ix = instructions.indexOf(in);
                    conditionals.forEach((b,i) -> {
                        if(b[0] <= ix && b[1] >= ix && source.add(i))
                            pending.addAll(sources.getOrDefault(i, Collections.emptySet()));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return source;
    }

    static IdentifyCall getInputs(
        String internalClassName, MethodNode toAnalyze) throws AnalyzerException {

        InsnList instructions = toAnalyze.instructions;
        Map<AbstractInsnNode, Set<SourceValue>> sources = new HashMap<>();
        SourceInterpreter i = new SourceInterpreter() {
            @Override
            public SourceValue unaryOperation(AbstractInsnNode insn, SourceValue value) {
                sources.computeIfAbsent(insn, x -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
                return super.unaryOperation(insn, value);
            }

            @Override
            public SourceValue binaryOperation(AbstractInsnNode insn, SourceValue v1, SourceValue v2) {
                addAll(insn, Arrays.asList(v1, v2));
                return super.binaryOperation(insn, v1, v2);
            }

            @Override
            public SourceValue ternaryOperation(AbstractInsnNode insn, SourceValue v1, SourceValue v2, SourceValue v3) {
                addAll(insn, Arrays.asList(v1, v2, v3));
                return super.ternaryOperation(insn, v1, v2, v3);
            }

            @Override
            public SourceValue naryOperation(AbstractInsnNode insn, List<? extends SourceValue> values) {
                addAll(insn, values);
                return super.naryOperation(insn, values);
            }

            private void addAll(AbstractInsnNode insn, List<? extends SourceValue> values) {
                sources.computeIfAbsent(insn, x -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(values);
            }
        };
        TreeMap<int[],AbstractInsnNode> conditionals = new TreeMap<>(
            Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a) -> a[0]).thenComparingInt(a -> a[1]));
        Analyzer<SourceValue> analyzer = new Analyzer<>(i) {
            @Override
            protected void newControlFlowEdge(int insn, int successor) {
                if(insn != successor - 1) {
                    AbstractInsnNode instruction = instructions.get(insn);
                    Set<SourceValue> dep = sources.get(instruction);
                    if(dep != null && !dep.isEmpty())
                        conditionals.put(new int[]{ insn, successor }, instruction);
                }
            }
        };
        analyzer.analyze(internalClassName, toAnalyze);
        return new IdentifyCall(instructions, sources, conditionals);
    }
}
```

Then, we also use a more elaborated example code:

```
public class IdentifyCallExample {
    private void toAnalyze() {
        (Math.random()>0.5? System.out: System.err).println(
            anotherMethod1(
                anotherMethod2("a", "b") ?
                    "c" : anotherMethod3("d", "e") ? "f" : "g",
                    anotherMethod4("h", "i") ? "j" : "k"
            ) ? "l" : "m"
        );
    }

    static boolean anotherMethod1(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }
    static boolean anotherMethod2(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }
    static boolean anotherMethod3(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }
    static boolean anotherMethod4(String str, String oof) {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalyzerException, IOException {
        Class<?> me = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass();
        ClassReader r = new ClassReader(me.getResourceAsStream(me.getSimpleName()+".class"));
        ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
        r.accept(cn, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG|ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
        MethodNode toAnalyze = null;
        for(MethodNode mn: cn.methods)
            if(mn.name.equals("toAnalyze")) {
                toAnalyze = mn;
                break;
            }

        List<int[]> invocations = new ArrayList<>();
        final InsnList instructions = toAnalyze.instructions;

        IdentifyCall sources = IdentifyCall.getInputs(me.getName().replace('.', '/'), toAnalyze);

        for(int ix = 0, num = instructions.size(); ix < num; ix++) {
            AbstractInsnNode instr = instructions.get(ix);
            if(instr.getType() != AbstractInsnNode.METHOD_INSN) continue;
            IntSummaryStatistics s = sources.getAllInputsOf(instr).stream()
                .mapToInt(instructions::indexOf).summaryStatistics();
            s.accept(ix);
            invocations.add(new int[]{s.getMin(), s.getMax()});
        }

        printIt(invocations, instructions);
    }
// remainder as in the simple variant
```

which will now print

```
┌────[    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Math.random ()D
│         LDC 0.5
│         DCMPL
│         IFLE L0
│         GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
│         GOTO L1
│        L0
│         GETSTATIC java/lang/System.err : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
│        L1
│ ┌─┬─    LDC "a"
│ │ │     LDC "b"
│ │ └─    INVOKESTATIC complex/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod2 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│ │       IFEQ L2
│ │       LDC "c"
│ │       GOTO L3
│ │      L2
│ │ ┌─    LDC "d"
│ │ │     LDC "e"
│ │ └─    INVOKESTATIC complex/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod3 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│ │       IFEQ L4
│ │       LDC "f"
│ │       GOTO L3
│ │      L4
│ │       LDC "g"
│ │      L3
│ │ ┌─    LDC "h"
│ │ │     LDC "i"
│ │ └─    INVOKESTATIC complex/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod4 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│ │       IFEQ L5
│ │       LDC "j"
│ │       GOTO L6
│ │      L5
│ │       LDC "k"
│ │      L6
│ └───    INVOKESTATIC complex/IdentifyCallExample.anotherMethod1 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
│         IFEQ L7
│         LDC "l"
│         GOTO L8
│        L7
│         LDC "m"
│        L8
└─────    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
          RETURN
```

This may still not catch every possible case, but could be sufficient for your use cases.

Comment: You rock! This works exactly as expected =) Good job! I'll give you the bounty when it allows me.