# With a java ASM agent, how to detect a collection modification in a object?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'am working in a Transparent Dirty Detection Agent ([tdd-agent](https://github.com/mdre/tdd-agent)). It work really well redefining the target classes to implement the setDirty()/isDirty() and set it when it detect a putfield, but I want to extend it to detect calls to add() in collections, for example.
How could I detect that call?

When the call is made with a complex parameters the generated asm  separates the field and the final invocation to the method and I'm not figuring out how to detect and handle it.

For example:

```
private List<Foo> listaFoo = new ArrayList<>();
public void testNativeCollections(){

        this.listaFoo.add(new Foo("text").setS("otro text"));
        
}
```

This block generate this asm:

```
 aload 0 // reference to self
 getfield test/OuterTarget.listaFoo:java.util.List
 new test/Foo
 dup
 ldc "text" (java.lang.String)
 invokespecial test/Foo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 ldc "otro text" (java.lang.String)
 invokevirtual test/Foo.setS(Ljava/lang/String;)Ltest/Foo;
 invokeinterface java/util/List.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
 pop
```

and I need to pair the first getfield with the last invoke interface to detect that this call will modify the object and after it insert a call to setDirty(). The main issue is that the code between the getfield/invoke could be arbitrary long and complex.

Comment: Calling `add` does not necessarily modify the collection. In case of a `Set`, for example, a return value of `false` implies that the set has not been modified. Further, it seems you are focusing on the easier scenario, where the code modifying the collection is inside the class whose “dirty” flag you want to set. But this doesn’t have to be the case. The collection might be returned by a method and the caller may one of the dozens modification methods, perhaps one not yet defined, as the API can evolve. You should probably rethink your approach…

Comment: Just one step at time. First, detect and instrument collections in a simple way.

Comment: Ignoring the big picture does not necessarily lead to a simple solution. For example, when you consider the complexity of detecting all modifications of a collection, you may find that replacing a collection with a delegating collection designed for this purpose (and implemented in ordinary Java code) is simpler than instrumenting every code pattern that could lead to a modification. Then, the instrumentation task reduces to finding the creation sites and injecting the code to wrap the created collection. If I get your use case correctly, it would affect the constructors of the target only.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to build java's own internal (as in, its private API, but, java is open source, there's that) static stackwalk analysis code, which is extremely complicated. One upside is that bytecode gen has been changed to be more palatable to it (e.g. `RET` is no longer being generated by `javac`, mostly for this reason).

You need to map each and every opcode that exists (and there a lot) to the effect it has on the stack. For example, `ALOAD_0` (which ASM at least helpfully flattens; `ALOAD_0`, `ALOAD_1`, `ALOAD_2`, `ALOAD_3`, and `ALOAD constant` are all flattened into just `aload` which helps a bit) has the effect of popping nothing and pushing 1 object onto the stack.

Doing that analysis:

```
          // stack at 0
aload 0   // stack at 1
getfield  // pops 1, then pushes value. stack at 1, remember: stack[0] = listaFoo
new test/Foo // stack at 2
dup          // stack at 3
ldc "text" (java.lang.String) //stack at 4
invokespecial test/Foo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V // stack at 2
ldc "otro text" (java.lang.String) // stack at 3
invokevirtual test/Foo.setS(Ljava/lang/String;)Ltest/Foo; // stack at 2
invokeinterface java/util/List.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z // stack at 1
pop
```

All the flavours of `invoke` require analysing the signature to know what impact it has on stack (-1 stack for every argument it has, and all but `invokestatic` an additional -1 stack for the implicit receiver argument - then +1 stack if its return type is anything but `V`.

Here your analyser should be capable of registering that that last `invokeinterface` is the one that pops the field you are interested in off the stack as receiver of an `add` method, thus, qualifying it for a 'dirty' flag.

I don't think a library exists that is public and maintained in a way that it is intended for analysis like this, but, I haven't looked all that much - perhaps now you know what to look for.

The JVM does this kind of analysis itself when loading a class. For example, if you have this bytecode:

```
ALOAD_0
DUP
GETFIELD someIntField
IADD
```

The verifier will abort with a `VerifyError` and this entire class will never even be loaded: It analysed that that `IADD` instruction, which pops 2 things off the stack and either [A] adds them if they are both ints and pushes that back on, or [B] all hell breaks loose if they aren't both int values - and it analysis that this is a B situation, because what's on the stack is `this` and an int - not 2 ints.

How does it do that? By applying the same principle: Analyse every instruction and keep track of what that does to the stack. In its case, it registers the type of each thing on the stack (`ALOAD_0` - okay, there is an object in `stack[0]`. `DUP` - okay, there is an object in `stack[1]`. `GETFIELD someIntField` - okay, there is now an int in `stack[1]`. `IADD` - okay, check `stack[current]` and `stack[current-1]`'s types? Uhoh, one of em aint `int` - VerifyError!

You'd do the same thing, except instead of tracking 'int', 'object', etcetera, you track specifically: "Ah, field this-or-that", and once you hit an `INVOKEVIRTUAL` to a method sig you know 'dirties' its receiver (such as `j/u/List.add(...)Z`), you can use your stack analysis to know exactly what it is dirtying.

Comment: Reading and readign, I landing on AnalyzerAdapter. Now looking how to use it in a correct way. It's seems it have a stack simulation that could do what I want.

Comment: @MarceloD.Ré if you want to go that route, you may have a look at [Java ASM Bytecode - Find all instructions belonging to a specific method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61022497/2711488) But as said in the comment at your question, I’d consider taking a different, simpler route…

Answer (score 0):

And finally I got it!
As I said, one step at time.

The trick was to use the AnalyzerAdapter class and keep a track about the name of the field in the stack so at any time you can know the field name who is referenced.

Here is the main code:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Marcelo D. Ré {@literal <marcelo.re@gmail.com>}
 */
public class WriteAccessActivatorAdapter extends AnalyzerAdapter implements ITransparentDirtyDetectorDef, IJavaCollections {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WriteAccessActivatorAdapter.class.getName());
    private boolean activate = false;
    private String owner;
    private List<String> ignoreFields;
    private List<String> collectionFields;
    
    HashSet<String> lastCollectionModifiedFields = new HashSet<>();
    
    // mapea la posición de la pila con el nombre del campo asociado
    private Map<String,String> stackToField = new HashMap<>(); 
    
    static {
        if (LOGGER.getLevel() == null) {
            LOGGER.setLevel(LogginProperties.WriteAccessActivatorAdapter);
        }
    }
    
    public WriteAccessActivatorAdapter(int api,
                                       String owner, 
                                       int access, 
                                       String name, 
                                       String descriptor, 
                                       MethodVisitor methodVisitor, 
                                       List<String> ignoreFields, 
                                       List<String> collectionFields
                                      ) {
        super(api, owner, access, name, descriptor, methodVisitor);
        this.ignoreFields = ignoreFields;
        this.collectionFields = collectionFields;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    
    
    /**
     * Add a call to setDirty in every method that has a PUTFIELD in its code.
     * @param opcode código a analizar
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void visitInsn(int opcode) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Activate: {0} - opcode: {1} ", new Object[]{this.activate,Printer.OPCODES[opcode]});
        // analizar las listas
        if ((this.activate)&&((opcode >= Opcodes.IRETURN && opcode <= Opcodes.RETURN) 
                               || opcode == Opcodes.ATHROW 
                               )) {
            // si hay colleciones agregadas, incluirlas como dirty antes de retornar. 
            if (lastCollectionModifiedFields.size()>0) {
                insertDirtyCollectionsFields();
                lastCollectionModifiedFields.clear();
            }
            
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Agregando llamada a setDirty...");
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
//            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_1);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, owner, SETDIRTY, "()V", false);
            //mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTFIELD, owner, "__ogm__dirtyMark", "Z");
        } 
        super.visitInsn(opcode);

        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "fin --------------------------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
        super.visitFieldInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "opcode: {0} - owner: {1} - name: {2} - desc: {3} - transient: {4}", new Object[]{Printer.OPCODES[opcode], owner, name, desc, ignoreFields.contains(name)});
        printStack(); 
        if ((opcode ==Opcodes.GETFIELD)||(opcode == Opcodes.GETSTATIC)) {
            // si se está accediendo a un field, preservar el nombre para futuras referencias.
            this.stackToField.put(""+(this.stack==null? 0:(this.stack.size()-1)),name);
//            this.owner = owner;
        }
        if ((opcode == Opcodes.PUTFIELD) && (!ignoreFields.contains(name))) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Modificación detectada!! Agregar el campo \"{0}\" a la lista.",new Object[]{name});
            
            this.activate = true;
//            this.owner = owner;
            
            printStack(); 
            
            insertDirtyField(name);
            
        } 
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "fin --------------------------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "opcode: {0} - owner: {1} - name: {2} - desc: {3} - isInterface: {4}", new Object[]{Printer.OPCODES[opcode], owner, name, descriptor, isInterface});
        printStack();
        // si el método coincide con una de las clases y métodos a monitorear, revisar el stack para verificar
        // que el campo sea un field.
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "activable object?: "+getJavaCollections().contains("L"+owner+";")
                                     +" - method: "+ name + "> activable? : " +getJavaCollectionsDirtyMethods().contains(name) );
        if ((getJavaCollections().contains("L"+owner+";")) && (getJavaCollectionsDirtyMethods().contains(name))) {
            // calcular la posición de la pila a acceder
            int stackOffset = descriptor.equals("()V")?0:descriptor.substring(1, descriptor.indexOf(")"))
                                                      .split(";").length;
            int stackIdx = this.stack == null ? 0 : this.stack.size() - 1 - stackOffset;
            String field = this.stackToField.get(""+stackIdx);
            
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "modificación de una colección detectada! stack idx: "+stackIdx+" field: "+field);
            if (this.collectionFields.contains(field)) {
                lastCollectionModifiedFields.add(field);
                this.activate = true;
//                this.owner = owner;
            } 
        }
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInvokeDynamicInsn(String name, String descriptor, Handle bootstrapMethodHandle, Object... bootstrapMethodArguments) {
        super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(name, descriptor, bootstrapMethodHandle, bootstrapMethodArguments); 
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "\n\n\n\n\nname: "+name+" - desc: "+descriptor+"   bs: "+ Arrays.toString(bootstrapMethodArguments));
        printStack();
        
        for (Object bsMthArg : bootstrapMethodArguments) {
            String bsMth = bsMthArg.toString();
            int dot = bsMth.indexOf('.');
            int bracket = bsMth.indexOf("(");
            if (dot > 0 && bracket > 0) {
                String cls = "L"+bsMth.substring(0, dot)+";";
                String mth = bsMth.substring(dot+1, bracket);
                LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "cls: "+cls + "   -   method: "+mth);

                if (getJavaCollections().contains(cls) && getJavaCollectionsDirtyMethods().contains(mth)) {
                    int stackIdx = this.stack.size() - 1 ;
                    String field = this.stackToField.get(""+stackIdx);
                    LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "modificación de una colección detectada! stack idx: "+stackIdx+" field: "+field);
                    if (this.collectionFields.contains(field)) {
                        lastCollectionModifiedFields.add(field);
                        this.activate = true;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "\n\n\n\n\n");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLabel(Label label) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Label: "+label);
        if (lastCollectionModifiedFields.size()>0){
            // si se ha agregado un collectionModifiedField, instrumentar add del campo
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Modificaciones detectadas!! Agregar los campos a la lista.");
            printStack();
            insertDirtyCollectionsFields();
            
            // resetear el campo
            lastCollectionModifiedFields.clear();
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, " --------------------------------------------------");
        }
        super.visitLabel(label); 
    }

    @Override
    public void visitJumpInsn(int opcode, Label label) {
        if (this.activate && opcode == Opcodes.GOTO) {
            // si hay colleciones agregadas, incluirlas como dirty antes de retornar. 
            if (lastCollectionModifiedFields.size()>0) {
                insertDirtyCollectionsFields();
                lastCollectionModifiedFields.clear();
            }
        } 
        super.visitJumpInsn(opcode, label); 
    }
    
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void visitEnd() {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "fin MethodVisitor -------------------------------------");
//        mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
        super.visitEnd();
    }
 
    private void printStack() {
        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
            if (this.stack != null) {
                System.out.println("stack size:"+this.stack.size());

                for (int i = 0; i < this.stack.size(); i++) {
                    Object o = this.stack.get(i);
                    System.out.println(""+o.getClass()+" :  "+o + " --> "+ this.stackToField.get(""+i));
                }
                System.out.println("--------------");
            } else {
                System.out.println("stack size: NULL <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ");
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Insert all field registered in the lastCollectionFields hashset.
     */
    private void insertDirtyCollectionsFields() {
        for (String lastCollectionModifiedField : lastCollectionModifiedFields) {
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETFIELD, owner, MODIFIEDFIELDS, "Ljava/util/Set;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn(lastCollectionModifiedField);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE, "java/util/Set", "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", true);
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP); // Descartar el resultado booleano de add
        }
    }
    
    private void insertDirtyField(String name) {
        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
        mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETFIELD, owner, MODIFIEDFIELDS, "Ljava/util/Set;");
        mv.visitLdcInsn(name);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE, "java/util/Set", "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", true);
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP); // Descartar el resultado booleano de add
    }
}
```

Of course, there's a lot of situation that it will not work. You must respect the "Tell, don`t ask" rule and "Law of Demeter" !!!

The full code is at github.